# Nuget-Referenced library not able import into other project

Tags: c#, nuget

I have 3 C# projects and all projects are using a 3rd party library RestSharp.dll as a reference. By using nuget I created packages for all these 3 projects. Now I'm using these packages in another project as a reference. But, in this new project I'm not able to refer to 3rd party library RestSharp.dll. When I try to install RestSharp it says package already exists.

Using below nuget command to package the project

```
nuget pack "project1.csproj" -Build -IncludeReferencedProjects -Symbols -Properties Configuration=Release -MSBuildVersion 14 -OutputDirectory "\\Reporname"
```

How to resolve this?

Comment: You must add some code. Witch version of nuget do you use? How do you reference the RestSharp.dll? (project.json; package.config; direct to dll). Do you have an error message?

Comment: @kalten, I was not getting any error while packaging. Using NuGet Version: 3.5.0.1938

Answer (score 0):

Able to resolve it by adding below lines in nuspec file.

```
<references>
      <reference file="RestSharp.dll" />
  </references>

  </metadata>
   <files>
    <file src="bin\debug\RestSharp.dll" target="lib"/>
  </files>
```